# ¿ Hacer un fadeout de una vista que hay debajo de otra?

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo un programa que al pulsar un botón aparece una vista superpuesta a la principal. Me gustaría que la vista que queda debajo se oscurezca un poco (fadeout) para que la vista que aparece superpuesta contraste mas. No logro hacerlo bien ya que el código que tengo me oscurece las dos vistas.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0
                 delay: 0.5 
                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
             animations: ^{ 
                self.view.alpha = 0.5;
             } 
             completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
             }];
```

Comment: ¿Desde dónde estás ejecutando esa animación, desde la principal o desde la superpuesta?

Comment: Desde la superpuesta y esta vista superpuesta esta dentro de la vista principal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pruebas con lo siguiente:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: 2.0
                 delay: 0.5 
                options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut 
             animations: ^{ 
                self.superview.alpha = 0.5;
             } 
             completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
             }];
```

Comment: ok gracias por el código